# Facebook Server IP Whitelist Range?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I've found that I can add multiple domains to my facebook app by including the server IP address in the "Server IP Whitelist" field and the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" field. It would be really nice to be able to add a range of IPs instead of a single IP address in the whitelist field.

Instead of 127.0.0.1, I've tried using 127.0.0.0, 127.0.0.*, and 127.0.0.1-127.0.0.100. None of which seem to work.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: have you tried `127/8` (or similar)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that syntax. Could you write out the entire IP, or... is that the entire IP?

Comment: That is equivalent to `127.*`

Comment: Ah, OK. Yeah, I tried doing that and facebook said that it doesn't meet the requirements of a valid IP address. :(

Comment: You could also try the longer `127.0.0.0/8` format

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work either. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither 127.1.0.0/16 or 127.1.* are accepted, it just says invalid ip format

Answer (score -1):

Go to your dns settings for your website hosting and copy the ip address it should be like 
11.11.11.111
If you are hosting in Azure you can go to the custom domains tab and copy the ip address

Im sure that you found an answer by now. This is for anyone who is searching the issue for the first time, because nobody ever posts an answer if they find one outside of stack overflow, lol.

Answer (score -1):

May be somebody looking how to set IP range to maximum - for all IPs(similar to remove Facebook Server IP Whitelist). I search it all day, may be i stuped, but answer is very simple - just set this field empty:D
I need it to working app access token from all IPs.